# I want to execute awk command from tcl script

Tags: awk, tcl

I want to execute the following command from my tcl script

```
exec /bin/awk '/Start/{f=1;++file}/END/{f=0}f{print > "/home/user/report/"file }' input
```

I'm getting this error

```
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

is it possible to execute such command from tcl

Thanks

Comment: This is probably a quoting issue but my tcl is too rusty to help here much. Though I suspect that `{}` quoting is going to be involved. Does replacing the outer single quotes with `{` and `}` help any?

Comment: thanks for your reply, Actually, I can't replace  single quotes with { and } because  "/home/user/report/" , I have it as a variable.

Comment: @aachraf show your code, how are we supposed to guess that ? Stack Overflow is about helping on fixing code, not about divination :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from tcl man page:

> When translating a command from a Unix shell invocation, care should
>   be taken over the fact that single quote characters have no special
>   significance to Tcl. Thus:
>
> `awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}' numbers.list`
>
> would be translated into something like:
>
> `exec awk {{sum += $1} END {print sum}} numbers.list`

So I would try without quotes (posted as answer as it can't fit properly in a comment, it's just a though from a quick search on google)

as per comment you may create the awk script in a var before like:

```
set awk_command "/Start/{f=1;++file}/END/{f=0}f{print > \"$tcl_variable\"file }" 
exec /bin/awk $awk_command input
```

Comment: I can't replace single quotes with { and } because "/home/user/report/" , I have it as a variable.
here is what i have exactly 
exec /bin/awk '/Start/{f=1;++file}/END/{f=0}f{print > "$tcl_variable" file }' input

Comment: Updated my answer (took some time to test as my tcl fu is rusty since I didn't do anythin on eggdrops for a while :p)

Comment: I'd use awk's `-v` option to pass the tcl variable: `set awk_body {/Start/ {f=1;++file} /END/ {f=0} f {print > prefix file}}; exec awk -v prefix=$tcl_variable $awk_body input`

Comment: In this case you may keep a one liner, the idea with the vars is to be able to print  before exec for informational purpose

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
puts [exec /usr/bin/awk \
           {/Start/{f=1;++file}END{f=0}f{print > file}} \
           invoke_awk.txt]
```

If you don't need to show the output:

```
exec /usr/bin/awk \
     {/Start/{f=1;++file}END{f=0}f{print > file}} \
     invoke_awk.txt
```

Note that in TCL, you don't group with single quote, but use either double quote or brace.

Comment: thanks for your answer, your solution works if i haven't a tcl variable in the command but I've f{print > $tcl_varible file}