# AWK doesn't accept TCL results with error awk: can't open file

Tags: awk, tcl, quoting

I'm trying to get result of a ping from `TCL` in `AWK` with the following code:

```
set n [exec ping 8.8.8.8 -c 2]
exec awk {"NR>=2 && NR<=4 { print }"} $n
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in startup script: awk: can't open file PING 8.8.8.8 ...
```

it seems that `AWK` gets `$n` not as an input but as a file.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109655/i-want-to-execute-awk-command-from-tcl-script) but although it seems the same question, I'm having different problem. I can RUN `AWK` inside my `TCL`. The problem is that it does't accept `Input` as a source from me and although I didn't us `-f` switch it still gets it as a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to execute awk command from tcl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109655/i-want-to-execute-awk-command-from-tcl-script)

Comment: Tcl allows you to simply use a pipe too, so you could turn the two exec calls into one, and just pipe the result to awk. For example like this `exec /bin/ps -ax | my_filter arg1 arg2 | awk {{ print $1}}`

Comment: @schlenk thanks, i changes my code to `exec ping 8.8.8.8 -c $count | awk "NR>=2 && NR<=4 { print }"` but it didn't work.

Comment: @Cyrus thanks, I found that quastion but although it seems the same question, I'm having different problem. in that question, problem is to run `AWK` inside `TCL` here the problem is that it does't accept Input as a source from me and although I didn't us `-f` switch it still gets it as a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 choices come to mind

1. hand over the ping output as the stdin to awk:

   ```
   set n [exec ping 8.8.8.8 -c 2]
   exec awk {NR>=2 && NR<=4 { print }} << $n
   # ..................................^^
   ```

   https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm
2. don't bother with the temporary variable

   ```
   exec ping 8.8.8.8 -c 2 | awk {NR>=2 && NR<=4 { print }}
   ```

You don't want the double quotes inside the braces: the braces are used to quote the awk body, and you don't want to pass the double quotes to awk.

---

Another option: since you just want the 2nd through 4th lines of the ping output, use Tcl and you don't need awk at all:

```
set ping [exec ping 8.8.8.8 -c 2]
set lines [lrange [split $ping \n] 1 3]
puts [join $lines \n]
```

or unreadably

```
puts [join [lrange [split [exec ping 8.8.8.8 -c 2] \n] 1 3] \n]
```